# Запрос из функции, которая возвращает пользовательский табличный тип обявленный в пакете

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Нужно сделать запрос `select` из функции, которая возвращает пользовательский табличный тип как результат динамического запроса.

Создаю пакет:

```
create or replace package prov_adm is
    TYPE test_rec IS RECORD (name varchar2(40),id number);
    type test_table is table of  test_rec;
    FUNCTION test_funct RETURN test_table;
end prov_adm;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY prov_adm IS
    FUNCTION test_funct RETURN test_table IS
        tt test_table;
        vsql tFormula;
        l_rc SYS_REFCURSOR;
    BEGIN  
        vsql:= 'SELECT ''qwe'' as name, 2 as id from dual';

        OPEN l_rc FOR vsql;
        fetch l_rc bulk collect into tt;
        RETURN tt; 
    END;  
end prov_adm;
```

При тестировании ошибок не возникает:

```
declare
  result prov_adm.test_table;
begin
  result := prov_adm.test_funct;
end;
```

Но когда пытаюсь сделать `select` из функции:

```
select * from table(cast(prov_adm.test_funct as test_table))
```

То получаю ошибку:

> ORA-00902 Invalid datatype: ...

Comment: может не совподают `id number` и `2 as id` так как один `int` а другой `double` или что то еще.

Comment: в test_rec id сделала integer и в процедуре изменила на: SELECT cast(''qwe'' as varchar2(40)) as name, cast(2 as integer) as id from dual. Не помогло

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В `Oracle` есть два контекста выполнения - `sql` и `pl/sql`. Не все то, что есть в `pl/sql` доступно для использования в `sql`.

Чтобы делать `select` из табличного типа, такой тип должен быть создан на уровне схемы, а не на уровне пакета. А на уровне схемы нельзя создавать тип `record` т.к. он доступен только в  `pl/sql`.

Поэтому, в Вашем случае, нужно будет создать на уровне схемы тип `object` и использовать его:

```
create or replace type test_rec is object (
   name varchar2(10),
   id number
)
/

create or replace type test_table is table of test_rec
/

create or replace package prov_adm 
as
 function test_funct return test_table;
end prov_adm;
/

create or replace package body prov_adm 
as
  function test_funct return test_table
  is
    tt test_table;
    vsql clob;
  begin
    vsql:= 'select test_rec(''qwe'', 2) from dual';
    execute immediate vsql bulk collect into tt;
    return tt;   
  end;
end prov_adm;
/

select * from table(prov_adm.test_funct)
/
```

Comment: Когда пытаюсь создать test_rec  с параметром force получаю ошибку PLS-00103 oracle encountered the symbol force when expecting one of the following ; is authid was substituted for "FORCE" to continue. Создаю без этого параметра и получаю ошибку при селекте и в контексте pl/sql и sql : ora-00932 inconsistent datatypes expected - got -

Comment: `Force` можно не использовать, т.к. это нужно только для пересоздания типа, который используется в других типах без их удаления. Что на счет остального - пример, на чистой схеме, у меня отрабатывает без ошибок. Попробуйте его исполнить на отдельной схеме или переименуйте все типы из примера как-нибудь иначе т.к. скорее всего у Вас могли возникнуть какие-то неоднозначности при совпадении имен типов.

Comment: да, все работает! спасибо

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста!

Answer (score 2):

Начиная с выпуска 12c ограничения на [использование в SQL пользовательских типов обявленных в PL/SQL контексте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/986770/217579) были частично сняты.

Например, для задачи как в вопросе больше не обязательно создавать SQL типы данных:

```sql
create or replace package testpack is
    type testrec is record (name varchar2(40), id number);
    type testtab is table of testrec;
    function testfunc return testtab pipelined;
end testpack;
/
create or replace package body testpack is
    function testfunc return testtab pipelined is
        r testrec;
        sqlstmt varchar (32000) := q'[
            SELECT trim (column_value) name, rownum id from xmlTable ('"qwe","qwa"')]';  
        rc sys_refcursor;
    begin  
        open rc for sqlstmt;
        loop
            fetch rc into r;
            exit when rc%notfound;
            pipe row (r); 
        end loop;
        return;
    end;  
end testpack;
/
```

Как статические, так и динамические запросы будут работать:

```sql
declare
    tt testpack.testtab;
begin
    select * bulk collect into tt 
    from table (testpack.testfunc);
end;
/

select * 
from table (testpack.testfunc);

NAME         ID
---- ----------
qwe           1
qwa           2
```