# Использование коллекций объявленных в спецификации PL/SQL пакетов в SQL контексте

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c, oracle18c

Необходимо вставить зачения в таблицу из коллекции объявленой в пакете.
Создаю следующее:

```
create table t_test (col01 number, col02 number);

create or replace package pack is 
    type numtab is table of number;
    function getnt (arg numtab) return numtab pipelined;
end pack;
/
create or replace package body pack is 
    function getnt (arg numtab) return numtab pipelined is 
    begin 
        for i in arg.first..arg.last loop pipe row (arg(i)); end loop;
        return;
    end;
end pack;
/
```

Пробую вызвать так (комментируя поочереди одну из двух вставок):

```
declare
    nt pack.numtab := pack.numtab (10,20,30);
begin
    insert into t1  
        select rownum, column_value from table(nt);
    insert into t1 
        select rownum, column_value from table(pack.getnt (nt));
end;
/
```

Ожидаю получить в таблице:

```
 col01 | col02
-------|-------
 1     | 10
 2     | 20
 3     | 30
```

Но в обоих случаях получаю соответственно следуюшие ошибки:

> ORA-00902: invalid datatype
>   PLS-00642: local collection types not allowed in SQL statements

В [списке изменений к версии 12.1](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NEWFT/chapter12101.htm#FEATURENO10014) говорится, что теперь не обязательно объявлять типы коллекций на уровне схемы для того, чтобы их использовать в SQL, в частности с `table` оператором:

> Other restrictions are also removed. The table operator can now be used in a PL/SQL program on a collection whose data type is declared in PL/SQL. This also allows the data type to be a PL/SQL associative array. (In prior releases, the collection's data type had to be declared at the schema level.)

Что делаю не так, и что всё таки изменилось?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55937304

Answer (score 8):

Существует ряд ограничений для типов коллекций обьявленных в PL/SQL пакетах (здесь и далее *локальные коллекции*), более подробно описанных в [этой секции документации](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/release_changes.htm#GUID-57E439FB-B196-46CB-857C-0ADAB32D9EA0):

> As of Oracle Database 12c, it is possible to bind values with PL/SQL-only data types to anonymous blocks (which are SQL statements), PL/SQL function calls **in SQL queries** and CALL statements, and the TABLE operator **in SQL queries**.

Допустимо использовать локальные коллекции только в запросах с `select`. В запросах на изменение данных `insert`, `update`, `delete` и `merge` ограничения пока не сняты. В документе  [генеральные направления развития продукта (см. слайд 24)](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/plsql/new-plsql-in-12c-2372822.pdf), ещё до выхода релиза 12c, этого никто и не обещал:

> Cannot bind into insert, update, delete, or merge

В зависимости от поставленной задачи, существуют различные решения.

**1. Классика - объявить на уровне схемы**

```
create or replace type numtab is table of number;
/
create or replace package pack is 
    function getnt (arg numtab) return numtab pipelined;
end pack;
/
create or replace package body pack is 
    function getnt (arg numtab) return numtab pipelined is 
    begin 
        for i in 1..arg.count loop
            pipe row (arg(i));
        end loop;
        return;
    end;
end pack;
/
```

И оба вызова из вопроса с удалением имени пакаета в `declare` секции:

```
nt numtab := numtab (10,20,30);
```

будут работать.

**2. Использовать табличные функции**

Как и ранее, возможно использовать в DML выражениях табличные функции возвращающие как тип результата локальные вложенные таблицы. Но передавать как аргумент функции такого типа, было и пока остаётся, недопустимо:

```
create or replace package pack is 
    type numtab is table of number;
    function getnt return numtab pipelined;
end pack;
/
create or replace package body pack is 
    function getnt return numtab pipelined is 
        nt numtab := numtab (10,20,30);
    begin 
        for i in 1..nt.count loop
            pipe row (nt(i));
        end loop;
        return;
    end;
end pack;
/
```

Такой вызов будет работать:

```
begin
    insert into t1 
        select rownum, column_value from table (pack.getnt);
end;
/
```

**3. Использовать PL/SQL bulk DML**

Предположим, надо получить результаты вставки, например, `id` сгенерированного неявно. Оператор `returning` в массовой вставке из подзапроса `select`, не поддерживается. Выражение `forall insert` пока единственный путь произвести изменения массово и вернуть результат проведённых изменений, и здесь локальные типы коллекций очень даже кстати:

```
drop table t1 purge;
create table t1 (id number generated always as identity primary key, col1 number);

create or replace package pack as 
    type numtab is table of number;
end pack;
/
declare 
    sources pack.numtab := pack.numtab (10,20,30);
    targets pack.numtab; 
    retids pack.numtab; 
begin
    select * bulk collect into targets
    from table (sources)
    ;
    forall i in indices of targets insert into t1 (col1) values (targets (i)) 
    returning id bulk collect into retids
    ;
    dbms_output.put_line (retids.count||' rows inserted.'); 
end;
/
3 rows inserted.

select * from t1;

        ID       COL1
---------- ----------
         1         10
         2         20
         3         30
```

**Дополнение: объявление коллекции на уровне схемы невозможно**

Если коллекция содержит типы элементов, которые известны только в PL/SQL контексте, то и объявить такую коллекцию возможно только локально. Например, коллекция с типом элементов `rowtype` теперь работает с `table` оператором:

```
create or replace package pack is 
    type t1rows is table of t1%rowtype;
end pack;
/
declare 
    sources pack.t1rows;
    targets pack.t1rows;
begin
    select * bulk collect into sources
    from t1
    ;
    select * bulk collect into targets  
    from table (sources)
    ;
    dbms_output.put_line ('targets: '||targets.count||' rows.');
end;
/

targets: 3 rows.
```

Как использовать в DML выражениях, см. решения 2 и 3.

---

PS проверялось на серверах: 11.2, 12.1, 12.2, 18.3.