# Можно ли создать коллекцию кастомного типа, не создавая в схеме новый объект?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Мне нужна коллекция в пакете, состоящая из элементов вида `(varchar, number)`.

Можно ли это сделать не прибегая к созданию нового объекта в схеме:

```
CREATE TYPE t_human AS OBJECT(name varchar(20), age number);
TYPE t_humans IS TABLE OF t_human;
humans t_humans;
```

только без **CREATE TYPE**?

Comment: Можно прямо в пакете объявить тип record, например, и дальше коллекцию с этим типом элементов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помимо того ,что в заголовках пакета можно объявить свой тип, например тип record

```
type r_some_data is record of (id integer, 
                           name varchar2, <...>);
```

Так же можно это сделать прямо внутри блока, использовать такой тип можно только в контексте этого блока

```
set serveroutput on

declare
type my_int_type is RECORD (id integer);
type my_int_table is table of my_int_type;

l_result my_int_table;

begin
execute immediate 'select level
from dual
connect by level < 11' bulk collect into l_result;

for i in 1..l_result.COUNT
    loop
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_result(i).id); 
    end loop;
end;
```

Таким образом можно сделать функцию ведущую себя аналогично pipelined функции, но без необходимости использовать для этого пакет.

Answer (score 3):

Начиная с версии 12c появилясь возможность, создавать пользовательские типы данных в пакетах и использовать их в SQL контексте. Некоторые ограничения, помимо отсутствия возможности определить функции, всё же есть, они подробно описанны в [этом топике](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/986770).

Простой [воспроизводимый пример](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=513d967a49324dc2be5e96b59dad94f6) конвейерной функции без создания нового объекта в схеме:

```
create or replace package pack as
    type thuman is record (name varchar2 (20), age number);
    type thumans is table of thuman;
    function getHumans (rc sys_refcursor) return thumans pipelined;
end;
/
create or replace package body pack as
    function getHumans (rc sys_refcursor) return thumans pipelined is
        r thuman;
    begin
        loop fetch rc into r;
            exit when rc%notfound;
            pipe row (r);
        end loop;
        close rc;
        return;
    end;
end;
/

select * from pack.getHumans (cursor (
    select trim (column_value), 20+rownum from xmlTable ('"Sam","Joe"') 
));

NAME                        AGE
-------------------- ----------
Sam                          21
Joe                          22
```