# Как выполнить SELECT из курсора или коллекции?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Есть на руках открытый курсор, возвращенный процедурой. Опционально, есть коллекция, куда переброшены данные из курсора. Нужно выполнить SELECT с групповыми функциями по данной коллекции или курсору. Как это можно сделать? Пример нерабочего кода, где я пытаюсь сделать выборку в коллекцию l_my_cur_table_returned:

```
PROCEDURE my_proc_main (p_var NUMBER) AS
  l_my_cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
  TYPE t_my_cur_rec IS RECORD
    ( COL_1 VARCHAR2(10),
      COL_2 VARCHAR2(10));
  TYPE t_my_cur_table IS TABLE OF t_my_cur_rec INDEX BY BYNARY_INTEGER;
  v_my_cur_rec t_my_cur_rec;
  l_my_cur_table t_my_cur_table;
  l_my_cur_table_returned t_my_cur_table;
BEGIN
  my_proc_2(out_refcursor => l_my_cur);
  FETCH l_my_cur BULK COLLECT INTO l_my_cur_table;
  SELECT col_1, max(col_2) 
    INTO l_my_cur_table_returned 
    FROM table(l_my_cur_table) 
    GROUP BY table(l_my_cur_table).col_1;
  CLOSE l_my_cur;
END my_proc_main;
```

Comment: SQL движок не знает что такое t_my_cur_table. Ему известны типы или объявленные в схеме или в спецификации пакета.

Comment: @0xdb единственной альтернативой может быть создание таблицы на время выполнения, поэлементная вставка коллекции, SELECT из неё и дропанье в конце процедуры?

Comment: Почему единственная? Обьявите тип для коллекции в схеме - это всегда работало и будет работать. В пакете немного сложней, здесь постарался [расписать поподробней](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/986770/217579).

Comment: Дабавте что получилось как PS в вопрос, завтра смогу посмотреть (у вас утро, а здесь ночь).

Comment: Здесь тоже ночь :) Ночная смена в СПб. Спасибо за помощь, что-то получается толковое способом с табличной функцией. Говорила мама учиться ж лучше, эх.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получилось сделать с табличной функцией. Хотя я и не в восторге, что пришлось заводить типы на уровне пакета. Код относительно вопроса такой:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE "MY_PACK" IS
  TYPE t_my_cur_rec IS RECORD
     (COL_1 VARCHAR2(10),
      COL_2 VARCHAR2(10));
  TYPE t_my_cur_table IS TABLE OF t_my_cur_rec INDEX BY BYNARY_INTEGER;
  FUNCTION get_table (p_var NUMBER) return t_my_cur_table pipelined;
  PROCEDURE my_proc_main (p_var NUMBER);
END MY_PACK;


CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY "MY_PACK" IS

FUNCTION get_table (p_days  NUMBER) return t_my_cur_table pipelined IS
  l_my_cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
  l_my_cur_table t_my_cur_table;
BEGIN
  my_proc_2(out_refcursor => l_my_cur);
  FETCH l_my_cur BULK COLLECT INTO l_my_cur_table ;
  for i in 1..l_my_cur_table.count loop
      pipe row (l_my_cur_table (i));
  end loop;
  return;
END get_table;

PROCEDURE my_proc_main (p_var NUMBER) AS
  l_my_cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
  TYPE t_returned_table_rec IS RECORD 
    (   
      COL_1 VARCHAR2(10),
      MAX_COL_2 VARCHAR2(10)
    );
  v_returned_table_rec t_returned_table_rec;
BEGIN
  OPEN l_my_cur FOR
    SELECT COL_1, MAX(COL_2) FROM table(get_table(p_var=> p_var))
      GROUP BY COL_1;
  LOOP
    FETCH l_my_cur INTO v_returned_table_rec;
    EXIT WHEN l_my_cur%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_returned_table_rec.COL_1||' - '||v_returned_table_rec.MAX_COL_2);
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE l_my_cur;
END my_proc_main;

END MY_PACK;
```

Comment: _Хотя я и не в восторге, что пришлось заводить типы на уровне пакета_ - почему неудовольствие, а что хотелось бы?

Comment: @0xdb - немного страдает замкнутость-модульность или как это умные люди называют. Пакет для всех, а я разложил тут своё хозяйство в общественном месте :) Хотелось бы в пакете описывать только процедуры и всё необходимое для работы процедуры держать в ней же.

Comment: _Пакет для всех, а я разложил тут своё хозяйство в общественном месте_  - вынесите всё "хозяйство" в отдельный пакет, и референцируйте оттуда - `myТypesPkg.myType`. В процедуре вы не удержите всего, что ей нужно, потому, что надо делится. Тут как в жизни - хочешь конфеткой поделиться с кем-то, так нечего её в кармане прятать ))