# Не работает SELECT из переменной объявленной в FOR-LOOP

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

```
declare
    i number;
begin
    for jj in (select * from BpmsHistoricProcessInstanceEntityImpl HPI
    where HPI.endTime is not null and HPI.endTime <= sysdate -1)
    loop
        select count(*) into i from jj;
    end loop;
end;
```

Выдаёт ошибку, что не существует таблица `jj`, как можно сделать запрос к `jj`?, Мне просто `jj` надо использовать несколько раз, для нескольких запросов.

Answer (score 2):

По видимому, речь идёт о вложенных таблицах. Если они объявленны в анонимном блоке, то их нельзя использовать в SQL запросах, они не видны SQL движку. Они должны быть объявлены как минимум в пакете. Подробнее [в этой теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/986771/217579).
Попробуйте следующий воспроизводимый пример:

```sql
create or replace package emppack as
    type empRows is table of hr.employees%rowtype;
    type empInfo is record (employee_id number, memo varchar2 (256));
    type empInfs is table of empInfo;  
    procedure proc (rc out sys_refcursor);
end;
/
create or replace package body emppack as
    procedure proc (rc out sys_refcursor) is
        emps empRows; 
        delemps empInfs; 
    begin 
        select * bulk collect into emps
        from hr.employees
        where employee_id between 110 and 112;
        dbms_output.put_line (emps.count||' employee rows found');

        forall idx in indices of emps
        delete from hr.employees e
        where e.employee_id = emps(idx).employee_id
        returning employee_id, first_name||' '||last_name bulk collect into delemps; 

        dbms_output.put_line (delemps.count||' following employees were deleted');
        open rc for select * from table (delemps); 
    end;
end;    
/
```

Так запустить и посмотреть результат:

```
set autoprint on serverout on
var rc refcursor
exec emppack.proc (:rc)
rollback

3 employee rows found
3 following employees were deleted

EMPLOYEE_ID MEMO                            
----------- --------------------------------
        110 John Chen                       
        111 Ismael Sciarra                  
        112 Jose Manuel Urman
```

Answer (score 0):

`jj` это не таблица, а одна запись из вашего подзапроса к таблице `BpmsHistoricProcessInstanceEntityImpl`. Запись `jj` содержит все поля запроса.

Циклы представленного вида позволяют итерироваться по записям из подзапроса.

```
begin
    for jj in (select 1 value from dual union select 2 from dual)
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line(jj.value);
    end loop;
end;
```

результат

```
1
2
```

Comment: А как мне получить именно таблицу?, мне таблица нужна в переменной

Comment: Задача не совсем понятно. Может быть вам надо сделать представление VIEW, с нужным подзапросом и затем его использовать в коде. Есть еще переменные CURSOR, но они тоже для циклов. Вот именно так как вы пишите сделать нельзя.

Comment: declare
    TYPE rd IS TABLE OF BpmsHistoricProcessInstanceEntityImpl%rowtype;
    r rd;
begin
    select HPI.*  BULK COLLECT INTO r from BpmsHistoricProcessInstanceEntityImpl HPI
    where HPI.endTime is not null and HPI.endTime <= sysdate -1;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(r.count);
     FOR i IN r.FIRST..r.LAST
    LOOP
        delete from BpmsHistoricProcessInstanceEntityImpl where id = r(i).id;
            commit;
 END LOOP;
end;

Comment: Но это тоже не совсем то

Comment: Если будет создан TYPE на уровне схемы, то в plsql на основе него можно будет создавать коллекции, из которых можно делать select.

Comment: Приведите пример, пожалуйста